Unwrapping an intermediate functional layer in Keras
I want to use the AblationCAM method, using Keras. I want to use the AblationCAM method, which requires creating a new model with the input of the original model and the output of the selected layer. However, the selected layer in my model is inside a functional API layer. Is there a way to unwrap an intermediate functional API layer while keeping the connections between layers? Or a way to access the output a layer within the functional API layer?
When I try to create a new model, I encounter an error stating that the graph is disconnected.
Input:
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
new_model = Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=model.get_layer(FUNCTIONAL_LAYER).get_layer('conv2_block1_0_bn').output)

Output:
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_6'), name='input_6', description="created by layer 'input_6'") at layer "zero_padding2d". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []


If your FUNCTIONAL_LAYER is nested within another layer or block, you must extract the specific output layer from that block to create a new model.
In this way we can extract the  Intermediate Layer:
conv2_block1_0_bn_layer = model.get_layer('conv2_block1_0_bn')
FUNCTIONAL_LAYER = conv2_block1_0_bn_layer.output  
new_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=FUNCTIONAL_LAYER) 
new_model.summary()

